# Are $|\sin(m)|$ and $|\sin(n+m+\frac{1}{2})|$ arbitrarily close?

Tags: real-analysis

$\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary. Does there exist an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that, for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\Big\lvert |\sin(m)| - |\sin(n+m+\frac{1}{2})|\Big\rvert \leq \epsilon ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: The expressions in title and the the body of the question are not the same. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Bernard: Obviously the question body is what was intended. I have taken the liberty of editing the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using $\sin x-\sin y = 2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2$, it suffices to find $n$ such that $\left |\sin\frac{2n+1}4\right |<\frac \epsilon 2$.
This means we want to achieve $2n+1\approx 4k\pi$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$, in fact $|2n+1-4k\pi|<2\epsilon$ is sufficient. This can be achieved and is a consequence of the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: Since we have absolute values here can't we set the phase shift down to just $\pi$ thus making $2n+1 \approx 2k\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\pi$ is an irrational number, the sequences given by $e^{in}$ and $e^{i\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$ are dense in the unit circle. The projection on the imaginary axis given by $z\to\text{Im}(z)$ is a continuous map, hence it preserves density. It follows that the sequences given by $\sin(n)$ and $\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ are both dense in the interval $[-1,1]$, and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $m>n$ such that the distance between $\sin(n)$ and $\sin\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Obviously that cannot happen for *any* $m$ or *any $m$ big enough*, always by density.